# Determining menu items to be shown depending on who logs in

Tags: yii2

I am developing a health information system. Its my first project in Yii2. However, i am having trouble at some point. I want menu items to be shown on the navbar to depend on who logs in. For example, if a doctor logs in, i only want menu items associated with him to show, the same case for nurses, pharmacists and so on..I think this could be implemented in the following segment of code in main.php file in layouts, though i don't know how. Please help.

```
 $menuItems = [
        ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
    ];
    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']];
    } else {
        $menuItems[] = '<li>'
            . Html::beginForm(['/site/logout'], 'post')
            . Html::submitButton(
                'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                ['class' => 'btn btn-link']
            )
            . Html::endForm()
            . '</li>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about RBAC, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#rbac

Create a role for each type of user and filter the menu off that.

```
$menuItems = [];
if (Yii::$app->user->can('doctor')) {
    $menuItems = [['label' => 'Patients', 'url' => ...]];
} else if (Yii::$app->user->can('nurse')) {
    $menuItems = [['label' => 'Medicines', 'url' => ...]];
}
```